Is SSHd Broken? I don't see input until I hit enter
Running Ubuntu 22.04 Pro, SSHd seems to be broken now.  When connecting, and typing anything (after authenticating with a key), the text doesn't display until I hit enter.  I can't imagine what I'm doing wrong.  This worked until recently.
This is with a forcecommand of Telnet -E 192.168.0.7
If I telnet manually after connecting to the server, it works fine.  Not when automatically telnetting.

To find out what's wrong (to [edit] into your Question, do not use Add Comment), do (typing blindly):
stty -a
echo $TERM

To fix it for now, do (still typing blindly):
stty echo

To investigate, check the value of $TERM, and how it affects your ~/.bashrc, try bash -x ~/.bashrc.
